# How many projects(within the same organisation) can one apply for in GSoC (google summer of code)?

Tags: programming, project

Not because one would want to take on two tasks, but so that if one project is  already filled/assigned,they could be assigned another one,instead of  being turned down from  the organization

I have seen answers about the number of organizations one can  apply to,but not the number of projects per organization

I am in my first year and completely new to [GSoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Summer_of_Code) (google summer of code) and have just about begun exploring..

Comment: What is GSoC?  Could you include a link or description for those unfamiliar?

Comment: Likely https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Summer_of_Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the [Google Summer of Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Summer_of_Code) I would interpret their student advice [from the FAQ](https://developers.google.com/open-source/gsoc/faq) to imply that you can apply to as many *projects* as you like, but can only be accepted in one. It doesn't seem to be the number of organizations, but the number of projects.

Caveat. I don't make the rules. But given that Google is pretty experienced in such things, I'd guess that if you apply to more than you should, that the system will kick out the extras.